# Difficulty proving / disproving the following equalities relations ( Big Ω)

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have left with some functions I can't find witenesses for proving/disproving Big Ω equalities relations.

Here are the three relations:

1. $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (i^3 - i ^2) = \Omega(n^4) $
2. $log(n-\sqrt{n}) =  \Omega(logn)$
3. $log(n+\sqrt{n}) =  \Omega(logn)$

For the first one I tried to split the sum but to no avail.
The second and the third - I don't even have an idea how to start proving/disproving this equality..

Thank you very much !

Comment: For the first one there are known formulas for $\sum i^3$ and for $\sum i^2$ where $i=1..n$. Namely $[n(n+1)/2]^3$ and $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$ respectively. This may help; I don't know what $\Omega(n^4)$ means, just not up on the notation.

Comment: For the 2nd and 3rd, L'hopital it. For the first, as coffeemath said use the formulae. Integral approximation is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k^3-k^2)\geq \frac{n^4}{4}-\frac{n^3}{3} = \Omega (n^4)
$$

The $\geq$ is due to comparison with the integral.
$$
S_2=\log (n-\sqrt{n})=\log (\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}-1))\geq \frac{1}{2}\log n + \frac{1}{2} \log n - \log 2 \geq \log n -\log 2 = \Omega(\log n)
$$
The first $\geq$ is due to $\log (\sqrt{n}-1) \geq \log \big( \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2} \big) $

can you handle the third one from here?

Comment: This is very good explanation. Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome